# python variable scope LEGB rule

Tags: python

```
def fun():
    print b

def pass_a(b):
    fun()
```

.

```
pass_a(2) raise: NameError: global name 'b' is not defined.
```

According to LEGB rules, I thought to find b, python would go up stack frames, and found b in the enclosed scope pass_a? Please correct my understanding. Thx.

Comment: `pass_a` is not enclosing `fun`, it's only calling the function. `fun` would need to be *defined* inside `pass_a` to be enclosed by it

Comment: "I thought to find b, python would go up stack frames" - Python never goes up stack frames to find variables.

Comment: @user2357112  [ahem](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28b9178023a445b1da2694774c265cd4b7a244ec/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1400-L1409).

Comment: @wim: Okay, yes, there are technically situations where Python will walk the stack looking for variables, most notably with `super`, but stack traversal is not included in the standard LEGB scope priority rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**E**nclosing" scope in L**E**GB refers to a [lexically enclosed](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/lexical-scoping-static-scoping) scope.

In the example below, `b` is a name which will can found in enclosed scope:

```
def pass_a(b):
    def fun():
        print(b)
    fun()
```

In your example, the `b` is contained in a (different) local scope, not an enclosed scope.

See [PEP 3104 -- Access to Names in Outer Scopes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).

Comment: in OP's example, isn't b is enclosed by fun(), fun() is enclosed by pass_a()? Therefore, b is in the enclosed scope of pass_a(), no?

Comment: No, what you are describing is a *frame* not a *scope*. The frames are created at runtime (function call) but the scopes are determined at definition time (module import).